# Practice for modeling class - multiple container relationship

Tags: java, database-design, generics, generic-programming

I have a class that could:

1. Have multiple types of containers
2. Have multiple types of implementations

and what I did to model so far is:

```java
public interface ChildClass {
    Container getContainer();
    ...
}
```

and one of its impl (have a total of two, could be extended though):

```java
public class ChildImplA implements ChildClass {
    ...
}
```

I have (as you might have already guessed) a `Container` interface:

```java
public interface Container<T extends ChildClass> {
    List<T> getChildren();
}
```

and two interfaces extending `Container`:

```java
public interface ContainerA<T extends ChildClass> extends Container<A> {
    List<T> getChildren();
}
```

and

```java
public interface ContainerB<T extends ChildClass> extends Container<    
    List<T> getChildren();
}
```

The generic `T` refers to the implementations of `ChildClass` and a sample implementation of any of the last two would be like:

```java
public class ContainerAImpl implements ContainerA<ChildImplA> {
}
```

I have a couple of related questions regarding how to (properly) model this in the database, and whether the design so far could have been better:

1. I have a `child_class` table with `container_a_id` and `container_b_id` with foreign keys to `container_a` and `container_b` tables. Though one of the foreign keys has to be `null` at all times, is this still a better practice than having `container_id` that could reference multiple tables?
2. Should I introduce a generic, say `P` to `ChildClass` as follows:

```java
public interface ChildClass<C extends Container> {
    C getContainer();
    ...
}
```

and have 4 implementations of it in total (instead of 2 for the moment) as follows:

```java
public class ContainerAChildImplA implements ChildClass<ContainerA> {
    ...
}
```

Please bear in mind that implementing 2nd question also brings in further complications (e.g. implementing a few other `DAO`s for different types of `ChildClass` implementations, instead of just doing:

```java
getJdbcTemplate().update(child.getContainer() instanceof CintainerA ?
                        "INSERT INTO child_class VALUES container_a_id = ?" :
                        "INSERT INTO child_class VALUES container_b_id = ?" ,
                child.getContainer().getId());
```

Comment: _"Have multiple types of parents"_ That sounds inherently flawed.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm working on a rule and process engine. A rule can be a part of a `Process` or a `RuleGroup` where process engine is not deployed. I'd appreciate if you could explain what might be wrong with this? Also, your comment suggests your answer to question 2 would be yes to introduce the generic, am I right?

Comment: When you say parent,  do you mean a parent class in the sense of inheritance ?  Or do you mean a parent object of an instance of your class (e.g. a node in a tree) ?

Comment: Oh sorry, I screwed up, should have been clearer. Editing now. I mean, container, not in inheritence meaning.

Comment: The example names of interfaces and classes it very difficult to understand the question. Also why are you counting implementations? There could be 0 or N implementations of any interface and that should not affect the question or the answers, so I feel I'm missing something here.

Comment: It does not affect the question, at least not directly. Maybe because the implementations could increase by the order of it could.

Comment: Also, if you could suggest names for the classes/interfaces it could be of help, thanks.